# Should I use a plural when describing a state (e.g., Multiple Product(s) Mode)?

Tags: grammatical-number

Let’s say that a product has two modes of operation: single and multiple. In the user manual for the product, the single mode has the header *Single Product Mode*.

What should be the header for multiple mode?

> Multiple Products Mode

or

> Multiple Product Mode

That is, should the *product(s)* be singular or plural?  And what is the rule that governs this usage?  Is it that when *multiple products* is used like an adjective, then it should not be plural?

Comment: I have several PCs, all configured to operate in *single user mode*. I don't know what *single **users** mode* would mean, if anyone were to use that form (which so far as I know, they *don't*).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing programming identifiers, which is specifically off-topic according to our help center. 

Comment: but can't this be in a user manual?  For example, "our game console has a single user mode and a multiple user(s) mode?"

Comment: @動靜能量 Yes, we always put the second word in the singular: single-user mode, multi(ple)-user mode, single-mouse mode, multiple-mouse mode, one-foot measurement, six-foot measurement, one-horse town, ten-horse town. We have a question or three about that here somewhere or whother.

Comment: If it's for a user manual, why are you using 'CamelCase' format as if it's the NameOfAComputerVariable?

Comment: I am asking for "multiple product mode" also, but I just put it together in one word just in case there might be a different rule, such as used as "multiple-product-mode"

Comment: Actually, this question could be clearly valid, if I am asking about, a user manual, say for a thermostat, which describes the thermostat having a Single Air-conditioner Mode, and a Multiple Air-conditioners Mode. Why do some people think it has to be related to programming and close this question down?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted twice? As per http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, it's in scope (word choice, grammar), not?

Comment: that's because when I first wrote my question, not only did I mention "Single Product Mode", but I also mentioned "SingleProductMode" if used as a variable name in programming.  Then people say "programming is not English"

Answer (score 2):

In English, where a noun modifies another noun, it hardly ever has plural inflection, even where it has plural meaning, eg.:

> *hatstand* = *a stand for hats*
>
> *flower garden* = *a garden for flowers*.

There are exceptions, but they are rare. (There is also a different construction where the qualifying noun is put in the possessive, and in that case it may be singular or plural: *man's suit*, but *children's home*)

So for your case in the user manual (or *users' manual*), "multiple user mode" is much more natural. In your code, you can call it anything you like.

Comment: Yes, so in a user manual, it could involve a switch that when you slide to the left, set it to "Single User Mode" and slide to the right, for "Multiple User Mode".  So it is a perfectly acceptable question, but I just don't know why people are so closed for their minds that they have to close the question

Comment: I think because Variable names need not follow any kind of English grammar, so questions about variable names are simple not relevant. Text in a user manual is different, but from your question it looked as if you were just talking about variable names.

Comment: you said "In your code, you can call it anything you like"... so that's the thing, the manager actually asked me to rename the variable. I think it could make sense to follow the general English usage rules when naming things